# update hashtable by another hashtable?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, hashtable

How can I update the values of one hashtable by another hashtable,

if second hashtable contains new keys then they must be added to 1st else should update the value of 1st hashtable.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us, to see how we can help? In other words, what have you tried?

Comment: So you're looking to merge two hash tables?

Comment: yes exactly latest with old hashtable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in second)
{
    first[item.Key] = item.Value;
}
```

If required you could roll this into an extension method (assuming that you're using .NET 3.5 or newer).

```
Hashtable one = GetHashtableFromSomewhere();
Hashtable two = GetAnotherHashtableFromSomewhere();

one.UpdateWith(two);

// ...

public static class HashtableExtensions
{
    public static void UpdateWith(this Hashtable first, Hashtable second)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in second)
        {
            first[item.Key] = item.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't capture one of the requirements "if second hashtable contains new keys then they must be added to 1st", and will most likely throw an exception

Comment: @ParmesanCodice: It meets that requirement *exactly*. Why don't you try it and see for yourself? From the MSDN documentation: "You can also use the Item property to add new elements by setting the value of a key that does not exist in the Hashtable... However, if the specified key already exists in the Hashtable, setting the Item property overwrites the old value." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item.aspx

Comment: @Luke, my apologies I was not aware of this behavior.

Comment: It would be great if C# has a feature like hashtable1.Update(hashTable2); :-)

or like Hashtable.Update(h1, h2);

Comment: @shahjapan: You can easily make your own extension method to do this. I'll update the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Some code on that (based on Dictionary):

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> pair in hashtable2)
        {
            if (hashtable1.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
            {
                hashtable1[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                hashtable1.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
        }
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution using LINQ (though, I code in 2.0 ;) ).

Comment: This doesn't compile. Is it meant to be real C# or just pseudocode?

Comment: @Luke: Thank you, I really should start coding in C# if I give answers on such questions...

Comment: It compiles fine now and works correctly for `Dictionary<K,V>`, but it won't work for `Hashtable`.